# Feed for responses for all SE sites?

Tags: support, notifications, feed

I just found the per-site response feeds like:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/<user-id>/responses
```

Is there a feed for responses on all SE sites?

Comment: your link not working

Comment: You need to replace <user-id> with a user ID ;)

Comment: ohky, sorry i have not notices that

Comment: do you mean something like inbox at network profile? for your case, its URL would be `http://stackexchange.com/users/1181090/penthi?tab=inbox` - all responses at particular sites seem to be there

Comment: Yes! But it seems, that there is no feed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, such a feed does not exist at this time...nor do we have plans to add one.  From a back-end standpoint, we don't aggregate this data, and it'd actually be tricky to do so without duplication or heavy query cost (one or the other, maybe both).

Comment: But where does the information on the inbox tab mentioned by gnat come from (http://stackexchange.com/users/1181090/penthi?tab=inbox)? Despite that, I just forgot, that it could be difficult to collect the data over all databases.

Comment: @Penthi - responses includes more than inbox, like revisions to your posts.  Inbox is a different beast, and truncates the content to keep size under control.

Comment: OK, so I keep collecting the site response feeds. It's not the best way, but works as I need it.